# type 'Future<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I used following function to get user Id from web service

```dart
Future<String> getUserid() async {
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  // Read value
  String userID = await storage.read(key: 'userid');
  return userID;
}
```

when useing this function error occured

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

this is what i have tried

```
otherFunction() async {

  final String userID = await getUserid();
 return userID;
}

Future<String> getUserid() async {
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  // Read value
  String userID = await storage.read(key: 'userid');
  return userID;
}

print(otherFunction());
```

still error msg shows as

> I/flutter (18036): Instance of 'Future'

Comment: Functions marked with `async` always return `Future`s.  You must use `await otherFunction()` too.  Also, please pay attention to which line the error message is reported against.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to **await** your function. If you are totally unaware of `Future`'s in *Dart*, you should read through [this comprehensive article](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures).

In *Flutter*, there are now two ways to handle this case. Either you want to call your function in a regular other function. In that case, you would either mark that function as `async` or use `getUserid().then((String userID) {...})`. If you were to use `async`, you would need to use `await` as well:

```dart
otherFunction() async {
  ...
  final String userID = await getUserid();
  ...
}
```

However, *in Flutter* it is very likely that you want to use your value in the *`build` method* of your widget. In that case, you should use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(future: getUserid(),
                       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                         if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container(); // still loading
                         // alternatively use snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done
                         final String userID = snapshot.data;
                         ...
                         // return a widget here (you have to return a widget to the builder)
                       });
}
```

Comment: I just want to return the value without creating a widget. how can I do that ?

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe I showed that in my answer. I also linked an article that explains it more deeply.

Comment: I have updated my question with applying your code. and still showing an error.

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe Have you read throught the article? It happens because you are still returning a `Future`. You would need to use `print(await getUserid())`.

Comment: otherFunction() async {
print(await getUserid());
}                                                        I used like this and it works, but output shows both error and return      I/flutter (31141): Instance of 'Future'
I/flutter (31141): 27808

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe That should not be the case. Something about the code you posted has to be different from the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi essa "conversão" da seguinte maneira:

```
Future<String> getData() async{
  return Future.value("Data to be converted");
}

void main() async {
  Future<String> stringFuture = getData();
  String message = await stringFuture;
  print(message); // irá ser impresso 'data to be converted' no console.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use Directly assign `Future<String>`  return value to the `String` variable.

Use `then` and get the String value.

Try like this:

```
otherFunction() async {
final String userID;
await getUserid().then((value) {
      if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) {
       userID = value;
      }
    });
 return userID;
}

Future<String> getUserid() async {
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  // Read value
  String userID = await storage.read(key: 'userid');
  return userID;
}

print(otherFunction());
```

Comment: This isn't good (or valid) code

1. You can't re-assign a final value
2. There is a method called **isNotEmpty** for checking empty strings

`if(value != null && value.isNotEmpty){...}`

Comment: yes, Thanks @Bus42 i update on my answers.